# Python 3.6 converting 8 bit binary to decimal

Tags: python

I am making a Python code in Python 3,6 that will prompt the user to input either 2 decimals up to 255 or an 8 bit binary number with the conversion to decimal, getting the user to input the 2 standard decimal numbers is no problem, also the same with getting them to input a binary number, however the once I print the binary conversion, it displays every binary number up to the corresponding number in decimal, lets say I type 11111111, it'd display, 1, 3, 7, 15, 31, etc up to 255

```
def add2():

    binary = input('enter a number in binary: ')
    decimal = 0
    for digit in binary:
        decimal= decimal*2 + int(digit)

        print ("This is the decimal equivalent" , decimal,)
```

This is the print result:

[image]

That is what my code is and I will attach a picture of what the printed calculation looks like. In the image you can see that it prints 8 times, each bit up to 255, realistically I just want the code to print the corresponding decimal integer, to what bits the user has put in, like for example if they put in 11111111, just print 255.

Comment: indentation matters in python. Your print is indented to be part of the for-loop, so it prints on every iteration. Dedent it to the outer level and it will only print once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just take your `print()` instruction out of your `for` loop, otherwise it will print every step to your answer.

Comment: Ohh I see, this has worked. Thank you, will up vote when I can.